# ssm-state manager-ansible playbook

Tags: python, mongodb, ansible, aws-ssm

I am executing a ansible playbook for ops manager installation in ssm.

Issues:

1. Ansible is using python2. how to make it to use python 3?

   ```
   --Output truncated---

   ----------ERROR-------

   Installing and or updating required tools: Ansible, wget unzip ....

   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py:44: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in the next release.

   from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature

   failed to run commands: exit status 2
   ```
2. Where can we find the log for the ansible execution in ssm?

Comment: `Ansible is using python2` => are you talking about the controller or the target ? What is the command/playbook/task.... related to your truncated output ?

Comment: Its the target,playbook is executed by ssm in the instance which has python 3 too

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html. See `ansible_python_interpreter` varialbe at the bottom if you want to fix the value.

Comment: yes how can we change it to python3 while executing in ssm

Answer (score 0):

### Running Python3

Currently the version of Ansible installed by AWS SSM (State Manager) is v2.8.5 running on Python 2.7

As mentioned in one comment, this can be changed at both a playbook level as well as a task level by setting a var:

At Playbook level:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  roles:
  - role_name
```

At Task level:

```
- name: Ensure botocore and boto3 modules are installed for Python2
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python
  pip:
    name:
    - "boto3"
    - "botocore"
    extra_args: "--user"
```

The actual issue is that Python 2.7 (which runs this version of Ansible) does not come with pip installed.

This must be done as a Task.

This affects the ability to write `filter_plugins`, as the Python libraries **must** be installed / available in Python 2.7 before the playbook is executed or the filter plugin will not register.
If running the plugin with Python3, the libraries must be installed for both Python 2 and Python3.

I believe there must be a workaround for this and will update my answer when it becomes available

### Logging

The Ansible logging available via the "Association" in the AWS console gets truncated. I would advise setting up the "Log to S3 Bucket" functionality as this logs both stdout and stderr for each execution (e.g logging to the same bucket the automation Playbooks reside in when testing - change this for production)